# Kettle mongoDB Input with ssl connection

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I try to connect with Pentaho Kettle 5 (community edition) to a mongodb though a SSL connection. I always get a connection timeout. If I try to connect via the command line or another tool like Robomongo everything works fine. Does anyone know how to enable SSL support for the mongodb-input?

UPDATE: I have the same issue with Pentaho 6.0

Answer (score 0):

There is no SSL support now. You need to add support for SSL in the source.

First add something in the settings

- https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-mongodb-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/mongodbinput
- https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-mongo-utils

And then add SSL support to it as it says here:

- http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/ssl/